# change the number of opened editors before closing value

Tags: java, eclipse, rcp

For my eclipse rcp application, I tried to change the "Number of opened editors before closing" programatically by modifying the extension point org.eclipse.ui.editors :

```
 IPreferenceStore prefs = getPreferenceStore(); 
 prefs.setValue("org.eclipse.editorss.maxEditorTabs",15) ;
((IPersistentPreferenceStore) prefs).save() ;
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5rS0.png

but it doesn't work, so I tried to use IWorkbenchPreferenceConstants.MAX_EDITORS_FROM_MODEL but I guess it's not available in the latest version of Eclipse anymore.

so my question is can i change this value or not ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Number of opened editors before closing" preference id is the `REUSE_EDITORS` constant in `org.eclipse.ui.internal.IPreferenceConstants`.

The preference must be set in the `WorkbenchPlugin.getDefault().getPreferenceStore()` preference store.

Note that both `IPreferenceConstants` and `WorkbenchPlugin` are **internal** so really should not be used.

See `org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.dialogs.IDEEditorsPreferencePage` for more details.

Comment: The IPreferenceConstants.REUSE_EDITORS constant determines whether the editor should be re-used or not when you open a new file.This constant does not have any impact on the maximum number of open editor tabs before they start closing automatically.

Comment: That is not how I read the source code, that preference is what is set in the "Number of opened editors before closing" field that you asked about.

Comment: thank you @greg-449 , after seeing your answer, I wrote this code :  `IEclipsePreferences instancePrefs = InstanceScope.INSTANCE.getNode("org.eclipse.ui.editors");instancePrefs.putInt(IPreferenceConstants.REUSE_EDITORS, 10);`  but it doesn't work

Comment: `org.eclipse.ui.editors` is not the id of the WorkbenchPlugin, that is `org.eclipse.ui.workbench`. You must end up with the value in the `org.eclipse.ui.workbench.prefs` file in the `.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings` folder of the workspace.